# Force scroll on content element

Tags: css

I have been searching far and wide, but I can't find it on the interwebs.

This is my problem.

I'd like to have my `<main>` element to have an `overflow-y:scroll`. 
No scrollbar on the body, but on the main.

I have made a pen to illustrate: http://codepen.io/magalielinda/pen/rymzBG/

As you can see the scrollbar shows, but it's not scrolling. Pourquoi? And how do I make it so it does scroll?

Here's my demo html for those of you that can answer it more easily this way:

```
<main>
  <div class="content__container">
  </div>
</main>
```

and demo css:

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

main,
.content__container {
  height: 100%; 
}

main {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.content__container {
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: aqua;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

Thanks so much!

**UPDATE**

I adapted from this solution. This is the result. http://codepen.io/magalielinda/pen/JWyVOM

Comment: You need javascript for that.

Comment: @jmargolisvt no you don't.

Comment: apparently you don't. Michael Coker's (what a cool name) solution worked.

Comment: @MagalieLinda lol thanks :) my parents gave it to me as a birthday present.

Comment: @MichaelCoker i'd like to upvote that reaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`height: 100%` will be `1000px` to accommodate the contents of `.content__container`. If you inspect `main, .content__container, body`, they're all 1000px tall. So all of the content is simply overflowing `body` and you've set `overflow: hidden` on `body` - no scroll bar.

You just need to limit the height of `main` so that there is overflow to scroll through. If you use `100vh` instead, things scroll as you would expect.

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

main {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.content__container {
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: aqua;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="content__container">
    foobar<br>
    foobar<br>
    foobar<br>
    foobar<br>
    foobar<br>
    foobar<br>
    foobar<br>
    foobar<br>
    foobar<br>
    foobar<br>
    foobar<br>
    foobar<br>
    foobar<br>
    foobar<br>
    foobar<br>
    foobar<br>
    foobar<br>
    foobar<br>
    foobar<br>
    foobar<br>
    foobar<br>
    foobar<br>
    foobar<br>
    foobar<br>
    foobar<br>
    foobar<br>
    foobar<br>
    foobar<br>
    foobar<br>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: @MagalieLinda welcome to SO btw. Be sure to upvote answers that you think helped, then select one of the answers as the accepted answer (checkmark by the answers) once you feel like the problem is resolved. Upvotes and accepting answers give positive karma ;)

Comment: Thank you. I will! I checkmarked yours, but it won't show because i'm a newcomer. But I will keep at it. 

P.s. I love your name! :D

Answer (score 0):

Give a `max-height` to your main:

```
main {
   max-height: 500px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Mpmvvr